# Append int in string to int[]

Tags: string, winforms, visual-c++, int

Let's say there have a string "123124125".
I wish to take out every 3 characters from the string and store into integer array.

eg,

```
int[0] = 123,
int[1] = 124,
int[2] = 125,
```

Let below String ciphertext is "123124125":

```
String ^ ciphertext;
int length1 = ciphertext-> Length;
int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;

while (count < length1)
{
    number[count1] = (ciphertext[count] * 100) + (ciphertext[count+1] * 10) + ciphertext[count+2]);
    count = count + 3;
    count1++;
}
```

Above is the code I wrote. The result is supposed to be 123 inside the `number[]`, but it not.

When `ciphertext[count]` times 100, it not use '1' to times by 100, but is its decimal number. So, "1" in decimal is "50", therefore the result is '5000' but not 100.

My problem is how can I append them 3 by 3 into a int[]? How can I avoid for using the decimal but to use 1 straight?

Sorry for my bad English. Really appreciate help from you, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT. I had suggested 9 - ('9' - char) but as gkovacs90 has suggested in his answer, char - '0' is the better way to write it.

The reason is that `ciphertext[count]` is a character so casting it to an int gives you the ascii code for that character not an integer. You could do something like `ciphertext[count]) -'0'`

For example, lets say that `ciphertext[count] is '1'`. The ascii value for the character `1` is 49 (see http://www.asciitable.com/). Thus if you do `ciphertext[count]*100` would give you 4900.

But if you do `ciphertext[count] -'0'` you get 49 - 48 == 1

So...

```
String ciphertext;
int length1 = ciphertext-> Length;
int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;

while (count < length1)
{
    number[count1] = 
        ((ciphertext[count] -'0') * 100) + 
        ((ciphertext[count+1] - '0') * 10) + 
        (ciphertext[count+2] - '0');
    count = count + 3;
    count1++;
}
```

Comment: Thank all!!It's work!
Thanks to gkovacs90 to suggest a way for me while Jimbo for the explanation and now i fully understand about it..
and thanks loxxy suggested me another method..=)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ciphertext[count] -'0'` to get the int value of the character.

You also can use atoi function on the substrings you want to convert to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out your error. Besides, How about doing it this way ?

```
string str = "123124125"; 

int i = str.Length / 3;

int[] number = new int[i];

while(--i>=0) number[i] = int.Parse(str.Substring(i*3,3));
```